How to search for C++ on Web of Science?
Is there a way to search for the exact keyword "C++" (i.e. the programming language) in the Web of Science database? Unfortunately, by default the ++ signs are ignored and I get millions of results.
On Scopus, it is possible by including the search term in curly brackets: {C++} but this does not help here.

Welcome to Academica SE! You should probably edit your question and move your Scopus comment directly into the question, as it might give people some clues to help answer you.

Did you try the words "C-plus-plus"?

@paulgarrett Great comment, thank you! It seems to work for the titles and keywords, but not for the abstracts.
